# Undestandig of definition of an affine subspace

Tags: affine-geometry

Consider the affine space $\mathbb{R}^{3}$. Then for example the set $ \{(x,y,z):3x-3y+z=0\}$ is an affine subspace. But $ \{(x,y,z):3x-3y+z=2\} $ and $ \{(x,y,z):x^2\} $ are not affine subspaces.
We have defined the affine subspace: $A = w_{0} + V = \{w_{0}+ v|v  \in V \} $ and A is the affine subspace of $W$ ($W$ is a vector space and $V$ is vector subspace of $W$). And we defined $dim(A)=dim(V)$.
Maybe it is quite simple, but I don't understand why $\{(x,y,z):3x-3y+z=2\}$ and $ \{(x,y,z):x^{2}\}$ is not an affine subspace and $\{(x,y,z):3x-3y+z=0\} $ is an subspace.
Thanks in advance

Comment: There is something missing in $\{(x,y,z)\;:\;x^2\}$

Comment: The set $\{(x,y,z)\;:\;3x-3y+z=2\}$ **is** an affine subspace of $\mathbb R^3$.